# Matrix equation : $\;AB=A^t\;$ implies the column space equals the row space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I have the following exercise:

> Let $\;A,B\;$ be $\;n\times n\;$ matrices s.t. $\;AB=A^t\;$ . Prove that the row space of $\;A\;$ equals its column space.

Now, this is what I've succeeded so far: I know that the dimensions are equal, and if we denote by $\;R_1,...,R_n\,,\,C_1,...,C_n\;$ the rows and columns of $\;A\;$ resp., I know that it is then enough to prove either

$$\forall\,i\;,\;\;\;C_i\in Sp\{R_1,...,R_2\}\;\;,\;\;or\;\;\;\forall\,i\;,\;\;R_i\in Sp\{C_1,...,C_n\}$$

, because of the dimensions' equality.

I also know that the rows of $\;A^t=$ the columns of $\;A\;$, but I am unable to give the last step and prove what I want: if $\;A=(a_{ij})\;,\;\;B=(b_{ij})\;$ , then we're given that

$$AB=\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_{ik}b_{kj}\right)=(a_{ji})=A^t$$

and it seems that from the above it should follows that the columns of $\;A^t(=$ the rows of $\;A\;$) are a linear combination of the columns of $\;A\;$, as $\;A\;$ is being multiplied *from the right* by $\;B\;$....and here I am ridiculously stuck!

Comment: One question: why should the row space of A be different from the column space of A? I mean, the row space of A is just the span of the linear independent row of A, and this generates a space of dimension $d$, $d \le n$. With the guassian algorithm you can easily show (if this is what you are looking for i can show it to you) that if the rank of the matrix is $d$ then you have $d$ linearly independent row and $d$ linearly independent column. I don't see why there is this matrix $B$ in your statement

Comment: @Ale The dimensions of the row and column spaces will be the same, but that doesn't mean that they are the same space (although will be isomorphic). Consider the matrix $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ In this case the column space is the span of $(1,0)$ whereas the the row space will be the span of $(1,1)$.

Comment: @Tom You are right, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have that the dimensions are equal, perhaps this will help:

$$
\operatorname{Col}(A^t) = \{ A^t x : x \in \Bbb{R}^n\} = \{AB x : x \in \Bbb{R}^n\} = \{A x : x\in \operatorname{Ran}(B)\}\subset\{Ax : x \in \Bbb{R}^n\} = \operatorname{Col}(A).
$$

Comment: Oh, my: so neat and simple. Thank you very much, @Tom. Of course, here we have that $\;\text{Col}\,(A^t)=\text{Row}\,(A)\;$ ...+1

Answer (score 2):

Let the column $n\times 1$ matrix $e_k$, be defined as follows $e_k=[0,\ldots,0,\underbrace{1}_k,0,\ldots,0]^t$. Then the $j^{\rm th}$  row of $A^t$ is given by
$A^te_j$
$$
 A^te_j=ABe_j=A\sum_{i=1}^nb_{ij}e_i= \sum_{i=1}^nb_{ij}A e_i \in\hbox{Range} A
$$
that is $\hbox{Range} A^t\subset \hbox{Range} A$. and the conclusion follows as you remarked.

Comment: Thanks a lot: very nice. +1